# Send VoIP Push notification in Cloud Functions

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, voip

I would like to send VoIP push notification from Firebase Cloud Function to my iPhone but getting an error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL: api.development.push.apple.com
```

I need to know if this is the right way to do so

**Here is my code**

```
var functions = require("firebase-functions");
const http2 = require('http2');

exports.sendVoip = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const storage = new Storage();
    const cert = storage.bucket('certificate').file('voip.pem');
    const key = storage.bucket('certificate').file('key.pem');

    const bundleID = 'com.cvit.albyrak'
    const deviceToken = '287f063372970c602cf80f889e74d0000e06649e6872c077f24fe8ce7b624b9c'

    const headers = {
        'apns-topic': bundleID
    };

    const options = {
        protocol: 'https:',
        method: 'POST',
        hostname: 'api.development.push.apple.com',
        path: '/3/device/' + deviceToken,
        headers: headers,
        cert: cert,
        key: key,
        passphrase: ""
    };

    const client = http2.connect('api.development.push.apple.com').request(options).setEncoding('utf8').on('response', (headers, flags) => {
        console.log(headers)
    });

    let data = ''
    req.on('data', (d) => data += d)
    req.on('end', () => client.destroy())
    req.end()

    response.send(request.body);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use https when connecting to the API, you can use the following code:

```
const options = {
        protocol: 'https',
        method: 'POST',
        hostname: 'api.development.push.apple.com',
        path: '/3/device/' + deviceToken,
        headers: headers,
        cert: cert,
        key: key,
        passphrase: ""
    };

const client 
http2.connect('https://api.development.push.apple.com').request(options).setEncoding('utf8').on('response', (headers, flags) => 
{ console.log(headers) 
});
```

You can see the previous in the [HTTP/2 Nodejs Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_http2_connect_authority_options_listener).

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Could you please provide the documentation or tutorial you followed to write the previous code? Please try to remove ":" from the https from the options and try again. I will update the answer with the previous.
Thanks

Comment: Please check this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@saminadhikari/send-push-notification-through-apns-using-node-js-7427a01662a2) as it explains in detail how to send voip push notifications.